# create a github workflow programaticly using github api

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api

I have a problem in injecting a workflow file into a private github repository

after making the app users go through the oauth2 flow and getting their github access token i'm making an api call to github api using octokit to inject a workflow file , if i change the path into any other file other than a file inside .github/workflows the file get injected normally , but when i change it to .github/workflows/fileName.yml i'm getting a 404 error
my oauth 2.0 scopes : repo,user,public_repo

```
await octokit.request('PUT /repos/{owner}/{repo}/contents/{path}', {
            owner: owner,
            repo: "",
            path: ".github/workflows/my-workflow.yml",
            message,
            committer: {
                name:owner,
                email:"assoulsidali@gmail.com",
            },
            content,
            headers: {
              'X-GitHub-Api-Version': '2022-11-28'
            }
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error creating workflow file:', error);
          });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the `workflow` scope to change workflow files.  That's because these can read secrets related to workflows, so additional permissions are required.

If you add this scope, then your operation will likely succeed.

Comment: After spending some time on debuging i found that one additional scope should be added to make the operation succed which is the workflow scope as you mentioned .